# Retrieve XML Node Structure - Bash

Tags: xml, bash, shell, xmlstarlet

I am trying to retrieve the node structure of a given XML file on a Windows machine through git bash. I have pretty much followed exactly what was mentioned [in this example](https://askubuntu.com/a/949667).

I am running the same command as in the example, which is:

```
xml sel -T -t -m '//*' \
    -m 'ancestor-or-self::*' -v 'name()' -i 'not(position()=last())' -o \
    . -b -b -n structure.xml
```

This command runs fine on a MAC (through the regular terminal). However, when I run it on a Windows machine through git bash, it only returns the root node of the XML structure, rather than the whole tree as expected.

What would be the equivalent command to run in order to get the whole structure? I have tried specifying different XPath Axes as specified [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp), but to no avail.

**EDIT:**

Say for example, I had the below XML structure

```
<node1>
   <node2>
       <node3>Whatever</node3>
   </node2>
<node1>
```

The command above should return (as it does on MAC)

```
node1
node1.node2
node1.node2.node3
```

whereas on Windows, it simply returns the root node, i.e. `node1`

Comment: Have you tried to change the attributes as per the rest of the answer in the topic you linked? There is more to it then just the code given as an exemple ;)

Comment: When you say attributes, what do you mean? I have tried multiple XPaths such as "ancestor", "descendant", "child" etc.

Comment: They offer more solutions in the comments regarding the display of the xml tree so I'm just asking if you also tried all the options there so that I can disregard them and think of something else :D

Comment: Oh right, yes I have tried the options. To be honest, the example that I've mentioned above is the perfect output as it displays the structure line by line with all nodes. That way, I can take the result and put it in an array and do with each node what I'd like. Please have a look at my edit in the question for what I mean. All in all, yes please do think of a solution with me other than what was mentioned in the example :D

Comment: @RigaCrypto I haven't had any luck coming up with a potential solution. Would you be able to help by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, try running the following compound command instead:

```
structure=$(xml el structure.xml) && echo "${structure//\//.}"
```

**Explanation:**

1. This runs a simpler `xmlstarlet` cmd using [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) to assign the result to a `structure` variable. The `xmlstarlet` command returns node names separated with a forward slash (`/`).

   For instance:

   > `node1/node2/node3`
2. After the `&&` operator we `echo` the value of `structure` using [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to replace forward slashes with dots (`.`).